# After delete trigger SOQL returns no rows

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, unit-test

I need help I'm losing my mid. I have a working trigger and I'm writing a test class. 
My data is isolated ( no @seeAllData=true)  
I create a master and children objects in my set up.  
I insert the objects and validate they all have id. I run the query that runs in the after delete trigger on master and in my test class it fetches the items but in the trigger it self no results are not pulled 
 WHY?

Comment: Have a look at the debug log when the test case runs to see what is going on before the after delete trigger fires.

Comment: That's what I've been doing for the past hour. There is no before delete trigger. Other triggers are disabled. The same query ( i print it out in both places and see the selection id is the same)  returns children in the test class but not in the trigger.

Comment: I'm assuming that the records aren't being deleted which is what's making the trigger run?

Comment: the master object is. I do call delete master in the test. I see the trigger kicks in. It runs a query "select detail from master where master id = : " and gets no results so it gives up. The same id...the same query, no results in trigger all results directly in test class.....I need a shrink

Comment: @user682217 If this is an **after delete** trigger and you are using the ID of the master record that was just deleted in the SOQL query then you won't find it. It has just been deleted. Perhaps you want a before update trigger.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I don't follow. When the after trigger runs the data is not committed yet so it is visible. I use the id from the triggerOldMap. My trigger works fine. I see it in the interface. I delete master and the sum of it's details is deducted from a lookup Product2.

Comment: @user682217 if you post your test code and the trigger and the relevant method from the helper class (if there is one), you'll get a much quicker solution.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I changed it to before and I see the trigger got executed. Now I really need a doc. How comes it was perfectly working in the interface? is this a test environment issue just like with asynchronous methods? Thanks for help. One shouldn't code after mindnight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment discussion above, I believe the problem was trying to run a SOQL query in an **after update** trigger for the record that was just deleted.

The record is indeed deleted at this point, so the SOQL query won't find it (with the exception of the [ALL ROWS keywords](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm)).

If you need to run a SOQL query for the record being deleted try a before delete trigger instead. Alternatively, try using the [oldMap trigger context variable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

Comment: yes I was using oldMap but it didn't worked in test Thanks